# Google Cloud Storage: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties

Tags: gradle, duplicates, cloud, storage

I have added the following dependency to my gradle file:

`compile('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.0.1')`

as per the Google documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries).

However, when I run my app, I get:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForManagerDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties
File1: C:\Users\Nathan\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-core\1.0.1\2b85bbbee4913a5fed34359d148c405dd8c98aac\google-cloud-core-1.0.1.jar
File2: C:\Users\Nathan\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-storage\1.0.1\dd6da899484a59e6beca89297f6e111506e1c477\google-cloud-storage-1.0.1.jar
```

I can't find any other references to `google-cloud-core` or `google-cloud-storage` in my project.

How can I find the cause of this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by removing
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.2.1'

I suspect that
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'

was importing it already.

I didn't verify this however.